# Solving $x^2 \equiv a (\text{mod }6)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

While preparig for the winter exams I am doing some old exam questions, but cannot get past the following question:

Find all $0 \le a \lt 6 \in \mathbb{Z}$ where $x \in \mathbb{Z}: x^2 \equiv \text{a (mod 6)}$

I can do some trial and error solution, but pretty sure it can be done in a more fancy manner... Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you looking for a method other than just squaring the integers from $0$ to $5$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that, by the Chinese Remainder theorem, if we know what $x^2$ is equivalent to mod 2 and 3, we know what it is equivalent to mod 6. Note that $ x^2 \not\equiv -1 \pmod 3 $ but $ x^2 \equiv 0, 1 \pmod 2 $.

From here, we see that $ x^2 \equiv 0, 1, 3, 4 \pmod 6 $ are the only possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You know that $x \equiv 0,1,2,3,4$ or $5\bmod 6$. Just check through the cases one-by-one:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
0^2 &=& 0 &\equiv& 0 \bmod 6 \\
1^2 &=& 1 &\equiv& 1 \bmod 6 \\
2^2 &=& 4 &\equiv& 4 \bmod 6 \\
3^2 &=& 9 &\equiv& 3 \bmod 6 \\
4^2 &=& 16 &\equiv& 4 \bmod 6 \\
5^2 &=& 25 &\equiv& 1 \bmod 6
\end{eqnarray*}$$
It follows that $x^2 \equiv 0,1,3$ or $4 \bmod 6$. In particular: $x^2 \not\equiv 2$ or $5 \bmod 6$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x^2 \equiv 0$ or $1$ mod $3$, but can be anything mod $2$.